# Which placed items give free buffs?

Tags: terraria

I'm building a boss arena, and I'm trying to figure out which items I should put in it.

For example, Campfires have a constant aura buff that increases life regeneration, so that's a no-brainer, and the Sharpening Station gives me a 10-minute melee buff whenever I click on it.

[image: Cozy Fire buff screenshot]

Are there any other such items that give free buffs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Auras**

[Star in a bottle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Star_in_a_Bottle) gives increased mana regeneration.

[Heart Lantern](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Heart_Lantern) gives increased health regeneration (and stacks with fire)

Dryad increases your defense, you can build a house near your arena and then move her into it

Sunflower's increase movement speed (and decrease monster spawn rate)

Honey improves health regeneration (while or after standing in it) however it will also slow you down so use wisely

[Enemy Banners](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Banners_(enemy)) Provide increased damage to and reduced damage from a particular enemy.

**Activates**

Bewitching Table allows you to summon another minion

Ammo Box - 20% chance to not consume ammo

[Sharpening Station](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sharpening_Station) increases armor penetration of melee weapons

[Crystal ball](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crystal_Ball) increases magic power

**Misc**

Using Asphalt as the floor will give you an acceleration as well as movement speed bonus

Heart Statues connected to pressure plates can give you a quick small boost to your health every now and then

Star Statues similarly give you a small amount of mana

Answer (score 2):

Expanding Aequitas's answer there's also:

- [Garden Gnome](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Garden_Gnome): Increases [Luck](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Luck#Garden_Gnomes), effectively increasing damage inflicted and reducing received.
- [Bast Statue](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bast_Statue): Increases defense by 5.